# Create and print a dynamic float array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying to create a dynamic float array. The user should type values untill a negative one is found. Then show the array in the screen. As I dont know the size of the array, everytime a valid value is entered I use realoc() to increment the size of the array

My code allocates memory for all the elements, but when I print the array, I get a segmentation fault. Don't know if I assign values in a wrong way or fail while reading them.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int createArray(float*);
void printArray(float *, unsigned int);

int main(){
    float *pArray = NULL;
    unsigned int arrayLength = 0;
    arrayLength = createArray(pArray);  
    printArray(pArray, arrayLength);
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Ask the user to fill an array untill he types a negative value
 * 
 * @param A pointer to the array we want to create
 * @return The final length of the array
 * 
*/
unsigned int createArray(float *pArray){
    float number = 1;
    int arrayLength = 0;

    while(number>0){
        printf("\nSetting number %d: ", arrayLength);
        scanf("%f", &number);
        arrayLength++;
        pArray=realloc(pArray, sizeof(float)*arrayLength);
        if(pArray==NULL){
            printf("\nERROR: Not enough memory");
            free(pArray);
            exit(0);
        }
        pArray[arrayLength-1] = number; 
    }


    return arrayLength;
}
/**
 * Prints an array given by the user 
 * 
 * @param Pointer to the array
 * @param Length of the array
 * 
*/
void printArray(float *pArray, unsigned int arrayLength){
    for(int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
        printf("\nItem[%d]: %.2f", i, *pArray+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: A dynamic array is not handled differently than a static or automatic array.

Comment: what is the point to `free(NULL)` ?

Comment: Touché, Didn't realized about that.

Comment: the line: `while(number>0)`  does not agree with the question nor the user prompt.  That is because 0 is not negative, but is excluded from the valid input values, so will cause the loop to exit.  suggest: `while(number>=0.0f)`

Comment: when writing `float` literals, the number must contain a decimal point AND a trailing `f`.   With out the decimal point, the number is an integer, not a float.  With out the trailing `f` the number is a `double`, not a `float`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always assign to a temporary pointer, then check (!=NULL) that pointer before assigning that temporary pointer to the target pointer,  Otherwise any failure of `realloc()` will result in a memory leak

Comment: to actually change, in main(), where the `parray` points, need to pass the address of the array, NOT the array pointer value.  I.e. call it via: `arrayLength = createArray(&pArray);`  then the prototype/signature for `createArray()` should be: `unsigned int createArray(float **pArray)`

Comment: for your future peace of mind, be consistent with types for functions and variables.  For instance in `createArray()` , the return type is `unsigned int` so the variable being returned should also be `unsigned int.`   There are 4 places in the code that contain this mismatch between parameters, variables, and return types,,,   Suggest reading/understanding the `man` page for each system function being called.  Especially look at the parameter types and the returned types

Comment: this line: `printf("\nItem[%u]: %.2f", i, *pArray+i);`  the expression: `*pArray+i`  is saying to take the value where `pArray` points, then add the value in `i` to that value.   I think you really want to take the address of the array and add the offset (in int widths) and return the value found there.  I.E. `printf("\nItem[%u]: %.2f", i, *(pArray+i));`

Comment: When the prototype, etc for `createArray()` is fixed, then need to always dereference that pointer one time at each access.

Comment: in general, returning 0 means `success` and returning 1 means failure so this line: `exit(0);`  is indicating the program wias successful, when it actually was not.  Suggest using: `exit(1);`   Note: the header: `stdlib.h` contains the definitions of `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`  and for clarity you should use those definitions.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reserving space for a local variable in `createArray()` whose lifetime ends with the function, you need to pass the address of `pArray`:

```
arrayLength = createArray(&pArray);
```

And then dereference the passed pointer to pointer in the function:

```
unsigned int createArray(float **pArray)
{
    ...
    *pArray = realloc(*pArray, sizeof(float)*arrayLength);
     if (*pArray == NULL) {
    ...
```

Comment: So inside the function pArray would point to the direction where the array is in memory, *pArray point to the memory where I want to store the numbers and **pArray would point to a single element? Excuse me if it's simple question but I never seen pointers before as im learning them now.

Comment: Yes, in your question you are passing a copy of `pArray` to the function, therefore you are reserving space for this (local) variable and when you exit from the function this variable no longer exists, in C you "simulate" pass by reference using the address of operator as in my example (Excuse my poor english)

Comment: Still got the segmentation fault in createArray(). Dont know what is happening, first assignement goes ok but now it always fails at the second one. Maybe because of this `**(pArray+arrayLength-1) = number;`

Comment: Try `*(*pArray+arrayLength-1) = number;` or `(*pArray)[arrayLength-1] = number; `

Comment: Thank you so much for being patient with me :). Now it works, but also the most important, I understand why. I also had to change this in printArray(): `printf("\nItem[%d]: %.2f", i, *(pArray+i));`

Comment: Glad to hear that :)